# What rose would be best for hip production?

Tags: plant-recommendations, roses, fruits

I am looking for a rose that produces a good crop of large hips. It has to be winter hardy and relatively carefree , but I will be able to prune, mulch, and, water it. It also will have to be disease resistant as I don't use chemicals. I found a hopeful looking rose, 'Jubilee'. This has good production and growth habit but disease resistance wasn't mentioned. What rose would be good for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fedco Trees](http://www.fedcoseeds.com/trees.htm) lists a couple of varieties in their catalog that might meet your requirements. See page 42 of the 2012 catalog:

- R. ‘Fru Dagmar Hastrup’:

  > Relatively low-growing form
  >   with rich green, deeply veined disease-resistant foliage that turns bronze in
  >   fall. Very large red hips. Recommended for the edible landscape. Z4
- R. rugosa ‘Scabrosa’:

  > One of the absolute best roses for
  >   the edible landscape [...] huge orange-red hips that can be the size of cherry
  >   tomatoes [...] beautiful flowers and large hips. [...] Extremely hardy. No disease
  >   issues ever. Z3.

Answer (score 4):

Along the New Hampshire seacoast (yes, we have one), [rosa rugosa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_rugosa) ("beach rose") is ubiquitous, as hedging, and the hips are, as Fedco says, "the size of cherry tomatoes".    It's *very* thorny.